# Query combined with filter depending on checkboxes values

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I would like to query with multiple filter criteria based on checkboxes conditions.
For instance, I can filter item by item checked, ok, but I would like to combine filter in that same query result by getting out all the items corresponding to the value in the following column of checked checkboxes.

Something like
`=query(A2:I;"select G, H, I where D = TRUE" & IF (A=TRUE;; WHERE I = filter(A2:B;A2:A=TRUE) ))`

Thank you for your help. Here's the sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qk3R2N9Pi0gnnJpNKPMk_WGI2Fh_fBHUgrXMS2fUy9k/edit#gid=388552420

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(query({A2:I},"select Col7, Col8, Col9 
                         where Col8 matches 
     '"&REGEXREPLACE(Join("♜",TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(IF(D2:D=TRUE,"|"&E2:E,"")))),"^[\W]+|[(♜)]","")&"' 
                         and not Col9 matches 
     '"&REGEXREPLACE(Join("♜",TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A=TRUE,"|"&B2:B,"")))),"^[\W]+|[(♜)]","")&"'"), 
                         "Nothing to show")
```

[image: Google sheets Query combined with filter depended on checkboxes values]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)

Comment: Glad I could help. As a side note, your sheet can become much "lighter" by using advanced formulas. I think you should consider rebuilding those as well.

Comment: Sorry, I have a subsidiary question : in column H I have mixed values, like : Blue, Green, Pink.. Could you please make your function more generic in order to handle such parameter ? Thank you

Comment: It handles any colours/values you put in column `E`. The formula has nothing to do with column `H`. In your sheet, column E is populated by the unique values from column `H`. Which means `E2` should have the formula `=UNIQUE(H2:H)`. So that is probably where you went wrong.

Comment: Yes it's true, sorry, I have for example the value : "blue, pink" in H, and if I checkbox 'pink' and 'blue' in DE, it doesn't sort out that value "blue, pink'

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example showing what I asked in comments of the 1st answer of marikamitsos

[image]